# [ ]operator for custom object : '[' illegal for class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here is my code where I try to access an element of class `Edge`:

```
#include <iostream> 
// for the sort()
#include <algorithm>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

struct Point{
    Point(int xx, int yy): x(xx), y(yy) { }
int x;
int y;
};

// class Edge: representing lines segments of the poly-line
struct Edge{
    // constructor
    Edge(Point p0, Point p1) : start(p0), end(p1){ 
        if (p0.x == p1.x && p0.y == p1.y) throw std::invalid_argument("Edge: Identical points!"); 
    } 
    // operator< defined for the sorting by increasing ordinate of the end point
    bool operator<(const Edge& e){ return (end.y < e.end.y); }
    // data members: start point and end point of the line
Point start;
Point end;
};

static void generatePoints(vector<Point>& p){
p.push_back(Point(50,50));
p.push_back(Point(200,50));
p.push_back(Point(200,200));
p.push_back(Point(50,200));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){

// Generate points for the poly-line
vector<Point> polyPoints;
generatePoints(polyPoints);

vector<Edge> polyEdges;
Point first = polyPoints(0);
Point last = polyPoints(polyPoints.size()-1);
polyEdges.push_back(Edge(last, first));
for (size_t i = 1; i < polyPoints.size(); ++i) polyEdges.push_back(Edge(polyPoints[i-1], polyPoints[i]));


int yCoordinate = polyEdges[i].end.y;

return 0;
}
```

Now, I have a vector of edges, like so:

```
vector<Edge> polyEdges;
```

and when I try to access it a specific member `polyEdges[i].end.y`, I get the following error message:

```
  'vector' : undeclared identifier
  'Point' : illegal use of this type as an expression
  see declaration of 'Point'
  'p' : undeclared identifier
  'generatePoints' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
  vector' : undeclared identifier
  see declaration of 'Point'
  'polyPoints' : undeclared identifier
  'Point' : illegal use of this type as an expression
  'polyPoints' : undeclared identifier
  'generatePoints': identifier not found
  'vector' : undeclared identifier
  Edge' : illegal use of this type as an expression
  see declaration of 'Edge'
  error C2088: '[' : illegal for class
  polyEdges' : undeclared identifier
  'polyPoints': identifier not found
  'polyPoints' : undeclared identifier
  left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
  'Point' : illegal use of this type as an expression
  error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
  error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union
```

It must be related with the overloading of the `[]operator`.

### Question:

Should I overload `[] operator` and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Please look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229476%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: Show us how you are populating `polyEdges`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `Edge`. I suspect you forgot an include and so `vector` here isn't the `std::vector` we know and love but something else that doesn't have `operator[]`... but that's just my best guess, need to see more code to verify

Comment: I would appreciate some explanation for the massive down-vote, even after all of the above requested information is provided!

Comment: You are using `vector` but haven't included `<vector>` or said `using std::vector`.

Comment: Please read what MCVE means: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @simplicisveritatis No, you should neither post a link to all of your code nor paste all of your code here. Instead, you should post a MCVE in the question itself, as explained above.

Comment: As it looks now @zenith was guessing right.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen I read it and here is a Minimal version

Comment: Alright guys, give the man his points back ;)

Comment: Where did my comment disappear? It was completely valid (and highest upvoted) before the OP decided to change the code in question, thus rendering my comment invalid! :/

Comment: @HappyCoder What do you mean?

Comment: I asked a question in my first comment (which is now deleted) that why was `Edge` deriving from `Point`? Now the code in question no more derives `Edge` from `Point`, my question was never answered, and my comment is also missing. Wondering what happened!

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, class `Edge` defines a line between two points and that is why was unnecessary included as base class, which was later corrected thanks to your remark. Which after the correction was probably judged as _obsolete_ and deleted to minimize the heavily commented OP

Comment: @HappyCoder I'm also wondering why are there still down-votes after all the recommendations were reflected in the edits?

Comment: No clue, many (including me) have taken back their downvotes as suggested by @Zharf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get some idea from this code. you no need to override `[] operator`. It uses the `[] operator` from `vector` class. Not from any of your class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }   
};

struct Edge {
    Point start;
    Point end;
    Edge(Point p0, Point p1) : start(p0), end(p1) {
        if (p0.x == p1.x && p0.y == p1.y) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Edge: Identical points!");
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const Edge& e) { return (end.y < e.end.y); }     
};

int main()
{    
    Point p1(0, 1);
    Point p2(2, 3);
    Edge e1(p1,p2);

    std::vector<Edge> polyEdges;
    polyEdges.push_back(e1);

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << polyEdges[i].end.y << std::endl;
    system("pause");

    //output is "3"
}
```

Comment: you were right, for some reason among the included header files there was something called `vector` which was hiding the omitted : `#include <vector>`.